# Как распаковать архив 7z или zip с помощью библиотеки 7zip?

Tags: c++, zip, 7z

Кто может помочь с тем как распаковать архив формиата 7z или zip  с помощью библиотеки 7zip для c++. Просто никак не могу понять саму библиотеку, а документации нормальной нет. Если кто может подсказать или показать код как это делается, буду благодарен.

Comment: хоть скажите какой библиотекой пользуетесь. Их миллион и еще одна.

Comment: @AlexeyVesker LZMA SDK на официальном сайте https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: @AlexeyVesker вы знаете как работать с этой библиотекой?